# awk, the function of quotation mark (") in number selection? (Linux)

Tags: awk

I have an input table, partially:

```
TCTTTTAAAGCCTCCTCAACTGTTTTAGGG  1       0
CACAACTGAAAAGTACAATGTGTTTGCTTC  1       0
CACCATATTTATTTAAAGGAGCATCTAAAT  1       3
ACGAGAAAAAAAAAAGGGGTGACCCCCTGG  3       0
CAAAATATTAATTCTTTACTATGAAACTTA  1       0
TTCTATTTTGTCGTGGTTAGCAACCATCAC  6       5
TAATAATAAAATAATGAAAAAGAAAAATCA  1       0
AAAGCATTTGAAGGTGACAAAAGGGAAAGT  20      7
TGCTAAGGAAGAATCATGGAAGAGTGTTTT  0       1
CTCCCTTCCTCGCAAACATGCTTGCCCAGG  0       1
AATAAAAATCAAATTTAGTGACGGGTTGAG  130     4
AGAACGAAGCTGATATAAAGACATCAAAGA  1       0
TGCCCCTAATGCAGCATCTCTCTCTCCCTC  1       0
CCACAAAATAATTACATGGCAAACACGAGT  1       0
```

I want to print all the lines with column 3 >= 120 and column 2 >= 420

I have got two different results by using and not using "" around the number.

```
(A) awk '$3>=120 && $2>=420 {print $0}'

(B) awk '$3>="120" && $2>="420" {print $0}'
```

Result of (A) partially, which seems to be what I want :

```
GTGTCATTTCATGCCTCATTCATCCTCATT  1375    439
TGAATTCTATTACTTGATTGACATTGACAG  541     301
TCTTTGGCGGTTGTTAAAGAATTTTCTGAT  823     203
TCTACACCTCAATATGCAAAACATTACATC  535     165
TTCAACAAATTAATTAAAATTGAATTAAAC  3010    627
GATATGTAAAAAAAATTATATTATATGAAT  609     173
```

Result of (B) partially, is not what I want :

```
TAATAATAATAATAAAAGAAGAAGAAAAGA  5       2
TATCTGAGCTATCAACTCAATTCATCGTCG  5       4
TTAATGATAAATTTATCTTAAAAGTTTAAC  62      23
TTCAACCCCCTCTCCTGGTGTGTGCCCTAG  45      7
TCCAAAGCCTTTAATGTGTACCGCGTGAAA  6       5
GGCAATGGGATACTCCTGTATGTTATTCTA  6       3
```

The question comes to my mind :
How does the quotation mark (") in number selection made the difference?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You may find [The GNU Awk User's Guide: 6.3.2.2 Comparison Operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Comparison-Operators.html#Comparison-Operators) helpful - note in particular *"Strings are compared by comparing the first character of each, then the second character of each, and so on. Thus, "10" is less than "9"."*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quotation marks force a comparison on the string representation of your numbers. Alphabetically, "42" comes after "120" (you then have "42" > "120"); numerically it doesn't (you then have 42 < 120).

Answer (score 3):

Perform the comparisons without the quotes, or they will be string comparisons that are performed lexicographically.

The tiny `awk` script may be further reduced in size by allowing the default action to be performed. The default action for a conditional test that does not have a `{...}` block is to print the current input line:

```
awk '$2>=420 && $3>=120' data.in
```